# By using higher order functions in Swift, does this affect Big O time or space complexity in terms of being more efficient?

Tags: swift, big-o, higher-order-functions

Learning about higher order functions that are available to collections in the Swift language has been exciting.  I think the answer to my question is no because it seems higher order functions simplifies the code that needs to be written for the overall underlying process.  However, I'd like a second opinion from the community just to be sure.

Comment: Of course, we would like to read a clear & clean code that's why higher-order functions are available in Swift

Comment: `map` performs a call to `reserveCapacity(_:)`, which is frequently forgotten about in the straight imperative analog. Repeated array reallocation has amortized `O(1)` time complexity per call (because it grows by a factor, e.g. 1.5, whereas the space required only increases incrementally), but it still does add a lot of overhead.

Comment: ... it wouldn't lead to a change in asymptotic complexity, but it will still have a  very sizable positive effect on large data sizes. For cases like this, asymptotic complexity is not a good marker of real world performance.

Answer (score 1):

Using higher order functions has no effect on the time & space complexity. Higher order functions are simply a wrapper to replace for-loops (and rid of mutable states)